# Programming in Latex: Conditionals

Tags: conditionals, programming

I'm trying to learn how to programming in Latex. I want to make an if-else-statement. What I will do is something like this:

```
\def\x{2}
{
\if x =2
Yes
\else
no
\fi
}
```

But it doesn't work exactly how I imagine it would be. Any suggestions how to fix this minimal example?

Comment: After `\def\x{2}`, use `\ifnum\x=2Yes\else no\fi`.

Comment: `\ifnum\x=2 Yes\else No\fi` a space after the two. If you have the code in different lines, the end of line acts as the space.

Comment: This is effectively Plain TeX usage and not LaTeX, but works there too, of course, if the correct syntax is used, of course

Comment: Arh thanks. What I want to do is to make an if-else statement i the preamble. It could be 
if x=2 
\geometry{left=3.0cm , right=3.0cm , top=4cm , bottom=4cm}
else 
\geometry{left=6.0cm , right=2.0cm , top=3cm , bottom=2cm}
end

Can this be done ?

I can only make an if-else statement between the begin and end document.